# sequential counts of a column based on unique identifier

Tags: r, gaps-and-islands

I wish to create a new row of numbers (count) based on the number of occurrences of a unique identifier(unique_id) in the first column (using R).
For example:

```
unique_id <- c("1a","2b","2b","1c","1c","1c","3d","3d","1e","3b","3b","3b","3b")

count <- c(1,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,1,1,2,3,4)

data <- data.frame(unique_id,count)
```

I've had a good search, but because I'm unsure of the correct terminology for this (still new to R), I was unable to find any relevant info.

Comment: For sure it's been asked several times. However, try this: `as.numeric(ave(unique_id,unique_id,FUN=seq_along))`.

Comment: variant: `unlist(lapply(rle(unique_id)$lengths, seq))`

Comment: @CathG It should be noticed that your solution only works if the vector is  ordered.

Comment: @nicola, indeed, I checked the vector format before and it seemed to me, the ids were supposed to be always ordered but probably a good thing to precise it, thanks